# What's the difference between Stream.map(...) and Collectors.mapping(...)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've noticed many functionalities exposed in [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) are apparently duplicated in [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), such as `Stream.map(Foo::bar)` versus `Collectors.mapping(Foo::bar, ...)`, or `Stream.count()` versus `Collectors.counting()`.  What's the difference between these approaches?  Is there a performance difference? Are they implemented differently in some way that affects how well they can be parallelized?

Comment: The collectors are useful when used as downstream operation of another collector. For example `groupingBy` takes a downstream collector collecting all the elements mapped to the same key. You couldn't use a Stream operation there.

Comment: Interesting that all of the collectors that take downstream collectors have gerund names, ending in `-ing`

Comment: @Tunaki How does that make the same methods different. Eg `stream.collect(Collectors.counting())` vs. `stream.count()` or `stream.collect(Collectors.mapping(Foo::bar), anotherCollector)` vs. `stream.map(Foo::bar).collect(anotherCollector)`. It seems a bit redundant.

Comment: True that there is no advantage to `collect(Collectors.counting())` but it does come in handy as a downstream collector, e.g. `collect(partitioningBy(String::isEmpty), Collectors.counting())` to split the results into 2 counts rather than 2 Lists

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The collectors that appear to duplicate functionality in `Stream` exist so they can be used as *downstream collectors* for collector combinators like `groupingBy()`.

As a concrete example, suppose you want to compute "count of transactions by seller".  You could do:

```
Map<Seller, Long> salesBySeller = 
    txns.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Txn::getSeller, counting()));
```

Without collectors like `counting()` or `mapping()`, these kinds of queries would be much more difficult.

Comment: worth to note that Java 9 will add `filtering` and `flatMapping` to `Collectors` as well so there’s a convergence…

Answer (score 3):

There's a big difference. The stream operations could be divided into two group:

- Intermediate operations - `Stream.map`, `Stream.flatMap`, `Stream.filter`. Those produce instance of the Stream and are always **lazy**, e.g. no actual traversal of the Stream elements happens. Those operations are used to create *transformation chain*.
- Terminal operations - `Stream.collect`, `Stream.findFirst`, `Stream.reduce` etc. Those do the actual work, e.g. perform the *transformation chain* operations on the stream, producing a *terminal value*. Which could be a List, count of element, first element etc.

Take a look at the [Stream package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) javadoc for more information.